# How to configure a jdbc realm in glassfish 3.0

Tags: java, security, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I am following this tutorial i found http://www.vitruvimente.be/?p=768 to create a JDBC realm, so i can login and out my users on my web app, but i have a problem.

But i have 3 different types of users in different classes(Admin,Buyer,Seller) I dont have a single class called users because their attributes are very unrelated.
I see in the tutorial they add a property called user-table, whay should i add there?

My question, is what settings should i add at the glassfish new realm page(localhost:4848)?
Can somebody give me some tips on how to configure this realm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *i have 3 different types of users in different classes(Admin,Buyer,Seller) I dont have a single class called users because their attributes are very unrelated.*

There's something wrong in your model design. You should really have a single table `User` with *at least* the login name and password. For the more specific user roles, you need a table `Role`. To relate them to each other, have a join table `User_Role` (which you map in Java as a `Set<Role>` in `User` entity). For the buyer/seller part it makes sense to have a `Product` table with a FK to `User` (the seller) and an `Order` table with a FK to `User` (the buyer) and `Product` (the ordered item).

After all, you should end up with a single `User` table/model which you could then just map in the realm.

Comment: I did that i created the new JoinColum, the application works correcty and i am ready to start preparing the realm, but i found a few difficulties in the configuration. I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620561/creating-my-first-jdbc-realmglassfish-v3 Could you guys give me a little hand?

Comment: But to use a join table in GlassFish, one needs to use some database view to make GlassFish understand that database structure, right? (Without such view, GlassFish expects a one-to-many relationship from some `T_USER` table to some `T_ROLE` (or `T_GROUP` in GlassFish-speak), based on values in a [user-name-column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7701/6nium5vr2/index.html) present in both tables, right?)

Comment: (As an aside: when mapping some tables `T_USER`, `T_USER_ROLES` and `T_ROLE` to GlassFish, one could of course make sure that `T_USER_ROLES` holds the String values that `@RolesAllowed` et al use, hence making GlassFish oblivious about table `T_ROLE`; see [GlassFish JDBC Realm Group Membership](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809081/glassfish-jdbc-realm-group-membership/6809340#6809340).)

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed your model as suggested by BalusC, I would recommend this [good tutorial here for setting up a JDBC realm with glassfish](http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html).