# Creating my first JDBC Realm(Glassfish V3)

Tags: java, security, jdbc, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I want to create a JDBC Realm for my web app. Since my users are very different from each other i need to have just one table, with the usernames and passwords for the realm, i decided to create a new table in my database called ROLE(oneToOne relationship with the other users table).

This is how my users domain model looks like:
[image]

I am following this tutorial http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html but i am stuck, i dont know how to continue.

I will post the configuration i made at the glassfish server and also my file sun.resources.xml so you can correct me if i am making any mistake:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0  Resource Definitions //EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_3.dtd">
 <resources>
 <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/myDatasource" object-type="user" pool- name="Derby_grupovina_grupovinauserPool"/>
 <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="Derby_grupovina_grupovinauserPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
<property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="PortNumber" value="1527"/>
    <property name="DatabaseName" value="grupovina"/>
    <property name="User" value="grupovinauser"/>
    <property name="Password" value="grupovina"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/grupovina;create=true"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
   </jdbc-connection-pool>
  </resources>
```

In the above comfiguration i have a few doubts, I dont really understand what should i ad at Group table and Group name Column.

The tutorial im following says that i should add security roles at the file sun-web.xml, and i wanted to do it but i dont know what to put in the configuratio. This is just what i added to that file but i think it is not correct. Where in that file should i add the role mapping and how should i configure it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
<context-root>/GroupBuySystem</context-root>
<class-loader delegate="true"/>
<jsp-config>
<property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
  <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class java code.</description>
</property>
</jsp-config>    
<security-role-mapping>
<role-name> </role-name>
<group-name> </group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
</sun-web-app>
```

The guy of the tutorial said he had not need for a web.xml, but i do need that file. What  should i add my web.xml?

This is my first jdbc realm, i am very confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume (from your previous question) that you don't have a group table. In fact you don't necessarily need one. JDBCRealm works with only a user table containing a group column as well.

In your Glassfish admin console change the following:

Group Table: Role

Group Name Column: userType

Since you used different typings (letter cases) for the word "role", make sure that the configuration values for your realm are exactly the same as in the table.